# ngrx createSelector with filter

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I have a selector that gets the current selected item:

```
const getSelectedItem = createSelector(
  getItemId,
  getItemsById,
  (itemId: string, itemsById: Record<string, Item>) => itemsById[itemId],
);
```

this works but I use it many times and I have to apply the `filter` operator when subscribing in the component so the underlying functions don't try to use an item that doesn't exist yet:

```
this.store.select(getSelectedItem).pipe(filter(Boolean)).subscribe((item: Item) => {
  // fetch reviews, etc.
  this.store.dispatch(fetchItemReviews({ item }));
});
```

But I have many components relying on this same logic. How can I encapsulate the `filter(Boolean)` in my `getSelectedItem`? This is the closest I have but sometimes it still emits `false`:

```
getSelectedItem = createSelector(
  getItemId,
  getItemsById,
  (itemId: string, itemsById: Record<string, Item>) => !!itemsById[itemId] && itemsById[itemId],
);
```

Just tagging `filter(Boolean)` after the projector function also does not work:

```
getSelectedItem = createSelector(
  getItemId,
  getItemsById,
  (itemId: string, itemsById: Record<string, Item>) => itemsById[itemId],
  filter(Boolean),
);
```

Comment: can you add your `reducer` code? initially thinking that `itemsById` should be in the state and filtered in the reducer

Answer (score 1):

I figured out something that works:

```
getSelectedItemRaw = createSelector(
  getItemId,
  getItemsById,
  (itemId: string, itemsById: Record<string, Item>) => itemsById[itemId],
);

getSelectedItem = createSelector(
  select(state => getSelectedItemRaw(state)),
  filter<Item>(Boolean),
);
```

The type of `getSelectedItem` is `MemoizedSelector<Observable<State>, Observable<Item>>`, so it needs to be used with `this.store.pipe(getSelectedItem)` in effects/components. The bad news is testing it is troublesome, I'm only able to test by setting `getSelectedItemRaw`'s value